# multiline regular expression with textpad

Tags: regex, multiline, textpad

I can't figure out how to make textpad perform a regular expression that extends multiple lines.

I tried using perl syntax with /myregex/m with m as a modifier but that didnt' work.  I can't see a checkbox or anything in the editor to tell it to do multiline.

anyone have any ideas?

Comment: I ended up just using visual studio...nevermind this question :/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is entirely possible, and simple :) You just use `\n`

This search:

```
we\nwill
```

Matches the end of line 1 and the start of line 2 in this dummy text:

```
this is a test and we
will see if it matches
multiple lines.
```

Answer (score 0):

Another way to do this is with [\s\S].  For example, if you wanted to find `<option>` tags in some HTML, you could search for:

```
<option[^>]*>[\s\S]*?</option>
```