# Select multiple lines of data using regular expression?

Tags: regex, textpad

I am working on a macro in `TextPad`. I want to select multiple lines of data between two stars. For example:

```
abc
*
cvb
vvnbj
vnbvn
*
cvb
```

I want to select the three lines between two stars. How we can select these using regular expression in `TextPad`?

Comment: I don't know Texpads regex engine, but apparently you can use `\n` to specify newlines: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7300732/multiline-regular-expression-with-textpad?rq=1

Comment: There are bugs with textpad's `\n` in capturing groups unfortunately

Answer (score 5):

This regex string should capture the stars and whatever is in between.

```
\*[^*]+\*
```

[Regex Tester permalink](http://regexpal.com/?flags=gs&regex=%5C%2a%5B%5E%2a%5D%2B%5C%2a&input=abc%0A%2aazasdasd%0Acvb%0Avvnbj%0Avnbvn%0A%2aasdasd%0Acvb)